# I want to add an API Gateway query string parameter to a cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint that I am using to download a file.  `http://apiendpoint.com/file`

We recently got a request to have a second file that we want to be able to get to and I want to add a query string parameter to it.  `http://apiendpoint.com/file?fileType="A"`

I can do in the console but I want to add it to the cloudformation template and haven't been able to figure out how to do so.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your current template and what you've tried?

Comment: https://github.com/cboath/DUDevopsclass

The template file is in there and I haven't really tried much because I can't find what values to use.  I did try the RequestParameters but that isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about using a parameter, you won't be able to do this in your cloudformation template, you'll have to implement that in the implementing service (i.e., the service that your API sends the requests to). API gateway in general is only granular to the `path` level and can only define `path` level parameters. And by that I mean define, not interpret (unless you're using advanced template mappings maybe, but from your template, it doesn't look like you are).

Oh, and you should have a look at [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/). It could help with cleaning up your template and making it more readable and easier to interpret since it adds some abstraction.